# HTML button tag does not word-wrap on iPhone/iPad

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

I am having trouble getting the <button> element to render correctly on the iPhone/iPad.

Here is the sample:

```
<button type="button" style="width:150px; word-wrap:break-word;">some very long text to make it wrap and go to another line</button>;
```

The idea is to have a fixed width button and the text wraps as needed. In newest IE, FF, and even desktop Safari (Mac and PC) things work as expected. The button width is fixed, the text wraps, and the button height automatically is increased to show the wrapped lines.

On the iPhone/iPad, the text wraps, but the button height does not increase. Thus, the user cannot see all the text.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make this work on the iPhone/iPad like on the desktop browser or is this a mobile Safari limitation?

Comment: Does `<button type="button" style="width:150px; word-wrap:break-word; overflow:visible;">` work?

Comment: I tried adding overflow:visible and it made no difference. Thanks for the idea, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. This took a lot of trial and error, but I actually got it to work. The key is to add "height:100%;" in the style string. Take out the height and the button does not grow horizontally. Add height and the button does grow if the text is long enough to cause a word-wrap. Guess without a height specified mobile safari gets confused. Go figure. I hate writing browser code. Sickening to think how many programming hours are wasted on crap like this.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some work I have found that adding this to the button style allows the button to render better on iOS mobile devices but you lose a little of the default round styling of the buttons:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give background color : #dedede.
Because IOS is not supporting "buttonface" color.

So just  add this on your css.

```
background-color: #dedede;
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score -2):

**Update:**

It appears now in iOS/iPad that line breaks set (physically or through CSS) on buttons works everywhere just fine.

---

If I recall correctly from my own testing, the iPad doesn't handle breaks on the button element at all. No idea if there is any way around it.

e.g. this won't work

```
<button>First<br/>
  Second<br/>
  Third<br/>
  Fourth<br/>
</button>
```

Comment: How is this relevant? OP is not using `<br>` tags.

Comment: I think in the past 12 years iOS has come a long way and has better formatting options: https://codepen.io/scunliffe/pen/ZExXjMG (all variations seem to work now). At the time, I found that iOS iPad had lots of issues with line breaks on buttons (regardless of how they were set, thus my example with the hard coded line breaks (not even depending on CSS).

Comment: Right, it would make sense if this were an answer on how to get around some limitation, but you are saying "here is an example of what _won't work" and it doesn't match what OP has in the question in terms of code... so it does not seem to answer their question _or_ provide a workaround.