# php login form not working in mobile browser

Tags: php, mobile

am driving myself nuts unable to find my mistake. If someone can see the mistake then,please save from my misery.This is simple login form working good in pc browser but no activity in mobile browser.

this is my code

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input autofocus name="username" type="text" style="font-size:30px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>
                <input name="password" type="password" style="font-size:30px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p class="center span5">
        <button type="submit" style="font-size:30px;" name="login">Login</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

**PHP** Code is

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$resultt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE admin_username ='$username' AND admin_password ='$password'");

$result = mysql_num_rows($resultt);

if ($result != 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultt)) {
        $type = $row['admin_type'];
        $user_info = $row['user_info'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['user_info'] = $user_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: what the error you are getting ?

Comment: Try changing `<button type="submit"` to `<input type="submit"`

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
<input type="submit" style="font-size:30px;" name="login" value="Login" />
```

instead of

```
<button type="submit" style="font-size:30px;" name="login">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the `<button type="submit">` with `<input type="submit">`

See this question and answer for your [refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464024/html-button-tag-does-not-word-wrap-on-iphone-ipad).

May be there is a compatibility issue

Answer (score 0):

As others said, use input type.

Your PHP is vulnerable to MySQL injection as you are putting user supplied data straight into a query without escaping/sanitizing/validating. I suggest taking a read of this:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php